# Currency in multiple cultures

Tags: javascript, currency

I have what I thought was a simple problem but am finding it hard to find easy solutions.  I have a donation page and people can enter their amount.  The problem is that some cultures use a period to indicated the decimal and others use a comma.  I am also rounding to the nearest whole number.

Is there an easy way to format the number such that:

12.95 will equal 13.
12,95 will equal 13.
12,000 will equal 12000.
12 000 will equal 12000.
12.000 will equal 12000.
12.45 will equal 12.
12,45 will equal 12.

Basically I need to strip out any commas and periods and create an appropriate whole number.  This needs to be based on the number actually entered, as some people may be using a European computer and keyboard but wishing to donate a US dollar amount, etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the shortest solution that will work an all given examples. I check for the third to last character, and if its comma or dot I assume it as an integer separator.

```
function parse(source) {
    var sep = source.charAt(source.length - 3);

    switch (sep) {
        case '.':
        case ',':
            var parts = source.split(sep);
            var norm = parts[0].replace(/(\.|,|\s)/g, '') + '.' + parts[1];
            break;
        default:
            var norm = source.replace(/(\.|,|\s)/g, '');
    }

    return Math.round(Number(norm));
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5C4aN/2/

Also have a look on [accounting.js](http://josscrowcroft.github.io/accounting.js/) which does good job formatting/parsing currencies.

Comment: Is there an easy way to add checking for NAN so that if someone does 5,5fg5 it will detect it correctly?  (Or any other typo that's not a number?)

Comment: I should say that I tried using a simple "if NAN" check but that doesn't recognize the comma.  So "44,55" will throw an error (when it shouldn't) but as is, the function will give 5f4 as a "5" (when it shouldn't).

Comment: @user1149499 you can use `Number()` instead of `parseFloat()`. It will return `NaN` in your case. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It looks like it's parsing 4,5 and 4.5 as 45, rather than the (more intuitive?) 4.50...is that something that's easily fixed by modifying the code?

Comment: @user1149499 whole this "magic parsing" doesn't make much sense. You must know the culture to correctly parse a number. How "4,555" should be parsed? Is it "four thousand five hundred fifty five" or "four comma five hundred fifty five"?

Comment: @user1149499 to make it worse, there are [Eastern Arabic numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals), and some Asian countries grouping digits not by three, but for two or four.